# Lua return value from function

Tags: c, lua

I have a question, when I'm doing like this

```
luaL_loadstring(luaState, "return 3, 4, 5");
```

I have on the stack 3 values, but when I try to call function

```
luaL_loadstring(luaState, vhs:get_sender_resolutions());

get_sender_resolutions = {function (self)
    local rresc = self.iface:GetSenderResolutionCount()
    local resolutions = {}
    for i=0,rresc-1 do
       local res = self.iface:GetSenderResolution(i)
       printdump (res, "#"..i.." = ")
       table.insert(resolutions, res)
    end
return 6, 7, 8
```

I have on stack just 1 value - function??  Is I miss something??

Comment: You tagged your question with 3 (three!) languages but the syntax of the code doesn't match two of them. I'm not sure your question can be related to all 3 languages. You need to either re-state your question or explain why is it tagged for all 3 languages?

Comment: @YePhIcK The `luaL_loadstring` and stack mentioned in his question are related to bindings between Lua and C (or potentially C++).  People following Lua are who have the expertise to answer this question.  People searching could find use in filtering to posts that contain those tags.

Comment: The code above for get_sender_resolutions is not complete; for one thing there is an unclosed `{`; there is also no `end` for the function. Show us the real code.

Answer (score 0):

`luaL_loadstring` wants to load a string; your second call seems to be calling `luaL_loadstring` with a table argument (or a function, it is unclear).